# Python optimization of simple login system

Tags: python, login-system

i don't have a problem with my code but i am very new to python and programming in general so i would like some inputs as to what i could do better.
I decided to do a very simple login / register system and i am hoping you have some input so i can improve myself. I don't post here so often and don't know if this is the sort of question usually asked, but i hope you will help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
username = ['mel1', 'mel2', 'mel3']
password = ['tyr1', 'tyr2', 'tyr3']

def log_sys():
    logged_in = False        
    log_user = raw_input('Please type in your username: ')
    log_pass = raw_input('Please type in your password: ')

    if log_user in username:
        index = username.index(log_user)
        if log_pass == password[index]:
            logged_in = True

    if logged_in:
        print 'You are logged in'
    else: 
       print 'Wrong username or password'
       log_sys()

def reg_sys(user):
    regpass1 = raw_input('Please choose a password: ')
    regpass2 = raw_input('Please retype password: ')

    if regpass1 == regpass2:
        username.append(user)
        password.append(regpass1)
        log_sys()
    else:
        print 'Passwords did not match'
        reg_sys(user)

def reglog_system():
    reglog = raw_input('Do you want to register or login?: ')

    if reglog == 'register':
        regname = raw_input('Please choose a username: ')
        reg_sys(regname)
    elif reglog == 'login':
        log_sys()
    else:
        reglog_system()

reglog_system()
```

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. You can't be that new; most Python beginners don't  use code like if logged_in: . I can only advise (being nit picky here) using clearer function and variable names.

Comment: Thanks Benji, I've been messing around with Javascript before so i know a little. Glad for your input!

Comment: Why not use a dictionary where the key is the username and the value is the password?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did not think about that Cristian, but i see now that it would be a better option. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer;  I'm not a python expert.

I would strongly suggest using an associative array or dictionary / hash instead of a list / array for storing usernames and passwords.  At a minimum, the performance for large lists of users will be better.

I would move the prompt for username when the user is registering into the function for that process;  It seems odd that you pass the username into reg_sys() but prompt in log_sys().

Your test for password seems flawed;  You only check to see if the first matches the second, without checking to see if either or both is None, an empty list, the empty string, or some other special value.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Got some criticism after all!

1) To make clear what your main function is, you should change:

```
reglog_system()
```

to

```
main()
```

2) Call your script with:

```
if __name__ == "main":
    main()
```

Makes it more portable. You can then call it directly or import it as a module

3) Use some return functions:

```
return raw_input("foo")
```

And handle the return within main(). It makes your code easier on the eyes and may help deciding when/where to deal with the result of a function.

Performance wise, I can't really criticise anything else, at least nothing springs to mind. For future planning, maybe implement hashing? SHA256 seems pretty robust these days.

Comment: @VictorVH ARE YOU NOT ENTERTAINED!?

Comment: Why #3?  It is a suggestion without a reason, and the reason isn't obvious to me, so I'd be surprised if it was obvious to the requester.

Comment: @Slartibartfast Thanks :). Edited for clarification

Answer (score 0):

i found out that if you use `example = input()` you can use `example` directly

Example:

```
name = input("Username: ")
if name == 'Username':
    passwd = input("Password: ")
    if passwd == 'Password':
        print("Login Sucsessful!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect Username or password.")
```